# How can be translated 1Peter 3:21?

Tags: grammar, 1-peter

Good morning. For some time I have a question about 1 Peter 3:21. I want to know all the possibilities of translating the text to know how to interpret the text. I noticed that there are textual differences in manuscripts, some of which have the relative pronouns in the dative (Textus Receptus) and others in the nominative. I want to tell me all the grammar translation possibilities(syntactically) both using the Textus Receptus and all the translation options using the nominative pronouns. I also want to know what the "eperotema" refers to. Was it used in LXX? If so, by what meaning? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: How many PhD theses would you like on all these topics?

Comment: Most of the standard commentaries cover all this material - have you consulted them?  See for example,  https://biblehub.com/commentaries/1_peter/3-21.htm

Comment: I have read various comments, but I have not read any comments that show all the combinations of words that can be done. For example, Ellicott presented only two translation versions. Are these the only ways to combine the words?

Answer (score -1):

@Florentin.......What you are asking requires tedious work. It's well known in critical commentaries (which I have in Logos Bible Software) that 1 Peter 3.21 has a difficult syntax. Anyhow, the sentence means that out of a good conscience, you make request to God to go on his side with Jesus instead of Satan and/or demons (there is background evidence for this, by the way, in which early Christians publicly renunciated Satan and demons during baptism).

Eperotema = request

> ἐπερώτημα, τος n: (derivative of ἐπερωτάωb ‘to ask for,’ 33.161) that
>   which is asked for—‘request, appeal.’ βάπτισμα … ἀλλὰ συνειδήσεως
>   ἀγαθῆς ἐπερώτημα εἰς θεόν ‘but baptism … is a request to God for a
>   good conscience’ 1 Pe 3:21. It is also possible to interpret ἐπερώτημα
>   in 1 Pe 3:21 as meaning ‘pledge’ or ‘promise,’ in which case it may be
>   classified under 33.288. Accordingly, the phrase συνειδήσεως ἀγαθῆς
>   ἐπερώτημα εἰς θεόν may be rendered as ‘a promise made to God from a
>   good conscience.’
>
> Johannes P. Louw and Eugene Albert Nida, Greek-English Lexicon of the
>   New Testament: Based on Semantic Domains (New York: United Bible
>   Societies, 1996), 406.